# Test a window gadget without vista or windows 7?

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456468(VS.85).aspx#_sidebar_basic_example

but i am on a pc without vista/windows 7.

Is there a way to test the hello world gadget???

regards

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Vista on virtual machine.